# Вставить значение в БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Изучаю php и sql помогите разобраться.
Сделал такой скрпт для добавления

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
$model = $_POST['model'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$name_brigade = $_POST['name_brigade'];

require 'configDB.php';

$sql ="SELECT  @variable := idBrigade FROM brigade WHERE nameBrigade = $name_brigade;
INSERT INTO auto(model,idBrigade,number) VALUES (:model,@variable,:number)";

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(['model'=> $model, 'number'=>$number]);
```

}

если запустить селект и инсерт в phpmyadmin все работает. но не работает в index.php.

Comment: Попробуйте `if(isset($_POST['model']))` или `number`

Comment: заменил SELECT  @variable := idBrigade FROM brigade WHERE nameBrigade = :name_brigade. Думал,что можно указать в запросе к бд переменную $.(видимо нельзя) ((

Comment: Нельзя два запроса за раз выполнить, а не переменную в строку подставить.

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете PDO. Для предотвращения использования уязвимостей PDO по умолчанию запрещает выполнять несколько запросов как один.

Разделите отдельно `SELECT` и `INSERT`. Тогда все заработает.